# Why does the python adds letters in dictionary?

Tags: python

I have been recently trying to make a program in python that makes text cipher but this is what happens :

```
text='abab'#the text we want to replace
result=''#we are going to replace it
replace_map={'a':'b', # a dictionary map to replace the text
   'b':'a'


}

for ch in text: #loop through every text in the loop
    if ch  in replace_map: # if the text is in the replace map 
        result += replace_map[ch] #then we are going to replace every letter in it from replace map

else:
    result += ch#else just add the value with no changing

print(text)#for comparison
print(result)#then print the text after replacing it
```

I want the result text to be 'abab' instead of 'babab'.
please help.

Comment: Badly indented python code is invalid python code. The behavior of your `else: result += ch` block depends on its indentation: the way it is now -- no indent -- makes it part of a `for...else`. Are you sure you want this and not an `if...else`? Please [edit] your question if the indentation of the code does not match what you have in your text editor.

Comment: It looks like your indentation is incorrect. Did you mean to indent the `else:` to be part of the `if` instead of being part of the `for`?

Comment: I released what is wrong``` else: result += ch``` is outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation in Python is critical! The interpreter is misunderstanding the flow of the program because the `else` keyword is not indented properly. Try using an IDE, which generally does well at indenting the code as needed (`if` and `else` statements on the same level, etc).

If you indent the code properly, it looks like the following. I have tested this code on my machine and I can confirm it works.

```py
text = 'abab'#the text we want to replace
result = ''#we are going to replace it
replace_map = {
    'a':'b', # a dictionary map to replace the text
    'b':'a'
}

for ch in text: # loop through every text in the loop
    if ch in replace_map: # if the text is in the replace map 
        result += replace_map[ch] # then we are going to replace every letter in it from replace map
    else:
        result += ch # else just add the value with no changing

print(text) # for comparison
print(result) # then print the text after replacing it
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your else statement is out of the for-loop, just add an indent to it, and it should give you your results.